# Python Class Calling Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with calling a def statement from another class. What I am trying to do is get the variable from one class then send it to the other class then send it back down again but I am having trouble doing it.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Logic:
   def __init__(self,measurements,measurements1,Text_Length_Left,Text_Length_Right):
       self.measurements = measurements
       self.measurements1 = measurements1
       self.Text_Length_Left = Text_Length_Left
       self.Text_Length_Right = Text_Length_Right

   as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inch=0.0254,ft=0.3048, yd=0.9144, m=1.0,km=1000.0, mi=1609.344,)
   def update_length(self, *args,measurements, measurements1, Text_Length_Left, Text_Length_Right):
       try:
           v = float(self.Text_Length_Left.get())
       except ValueError:
           self.Text_Length_Left.set('')
           self.Text_Length_Right.set('')
           return
       m = v * self.as_meter [self.measurements.get()]
       r = m/self.as_meter[self.measurements1.get()]
       self.Text_Length_Right.set("{:.3g}".format(r))

class GUI:
   def __init__(self,root):
       global a,b,c,d
       self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
       self.notebook.pack()

       self.length_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
       self.weight_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
       self.temperature_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
       self.help_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

       self.notebook.add(self.length_frame, text = 'Length')

       #Combobox
       self.measurements = StringVar()
       self.Combobox_Length_Left = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements, values = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state=['readonly'])
       self.Combobox_Length_Left.current(5)
       a = self.measurements
       self.measurements.trace('w', Logic.self.update_length())
       self.Combobox_Length_Left.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

       self.measurements1 = StringVar()
       self.Combobox_Length_Right = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements1, value = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state = ['readonly'])
       self.Combobox_Length_Right.current(5)
       b = self.measurements1
       self.measurements1.trace('w', Logic.self.update_length())
       self.Combobox_Length_Right.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

       #Labels
       self.Conversion = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'Convertion:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)
       self.Label_Blank = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = '').grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
       self.Label_To2 = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
       self.Label_To = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

       #Entry Boxes
       self.Text_Length_Left = StringVar()
       self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
       c = self.Text_Length_Left
       self.Text_Length_Left.trace('w', Logic.self.update_length())
       self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

       self.Text_Length_Right = StringVar()
       d = self.Text_Length_Right
       self.Entry_Length_Right = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Right,width = 13, state='readonly')
       self.Entry_Length_Right.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

       Logic(a,b,c,d)




root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.title('Metric Calculator')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my working code using inheritance of classes:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Convertion:
    as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inch=0.0254,ft=0.3048, yd=0.9144, m=1.0,km=1000.0, mi=1609.344,)
    def update_length(self, *args):
        try:
            v = float(self.Text_Length_Left.get())
        except ValueError:
            self.Text_Length_Left.set('')
            self.Text_Length_Right.set('')
            return
        m = v * self.as_meter [self.measurements.get()]
        r = m/self.as_meter[self.measurements1.get()]
        self.Text_Length_Right.set("{:.5g}".format(r))

class GUI(Convertion):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.notebook.pack()

        self.length_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.length_frame, text = 'Length')

        #Combobox
        self.measurements = StringVar()
        self.Combobox_Length_Left = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements, values = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state=['readonly'])
        self.Combobox_Length_Left.current(5)
        self.measurements.trace('w', self.update_length)
        self.Combobox_Length_Left.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        self.measurements1 = StringVar()
        self.Combobox_Length_Right = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements1, value = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state = ['readonly'])
        self.Combobox_Length_Right.current(5)
        self.measurements1.trace('w', self.update_length)
        self.Combobox_Length_Right.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        #Labels
        self.Conversion = Label(self.length_frame, text = 'Conversion:')
        self.Conversion.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)

        self.Label_Blank = Label(self.length_frame, text = '')
        self.Label_Blank.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        self.Label_To2 = Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to')
        self.Label_To2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

       self.Label_To = Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to')
       self.Label_To.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        #Entry Boxes
        self.Text_Length_Left = StringVar()
        self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
        self.Text_Length_Left.trace('w', self.update_length)
        self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.Text_Length_Right = StringVar()
        self.Entry_Length_Right = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Right,width = 13, state='readonly')
        self.Entry_Length_Right.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.title('Metric Calculator')
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

I am just trying to get the first one to work but I am struggling at it. 
Thanks for any help!

Edit:

The question is how can I make the first program work?
The error I'm getting is `self.measurements.trace('w', Logic.self.update_length())
AttributeError: type object 'Logic' has no attribute 'self'`

Comment: What is the question? Tell us what is it that is not working. There is like 100 lines of codes, surely the problem can be reproduced with a minimalist example.

Comment: Ha then its simple. The class itself does not have a self attribute. You have to instantiate the class and the call the method. for instance Logic().update_length() should be a start. Off course you will have to provide the proper arguments to both function calls. Logic() will call the __init__ function in case you wonder.

Comment: I tried it and got this error `self.measurements.trace('w', Logic().self.update_length())
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'measurements', 'measurements1', 'Text_Length_Left', and 'Text_Length_Right'`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a more basic misunderstanding of how class methods work. Without understanding more what the code is supposed to do, I think I can only give some basic advice (as there is a lot that is wrong with your code).

**Instance methods --** There are three types of methods you can use: instance methods, class methods, and static methods. Instance methods are of the most common variety. For example, I have created a class that defines a point, and has a method for shifting the point:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.position = [x, y]

    def shift(self, dx, dy):
        self.position[0] += dx
        self.position[1] += dy
```

The shift method is an *instance method* because it does not have the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorators (I am going to ignore what these mean for simplicity). An instance method may only operate on an instance of the class it is attached to, it cannot operate on the class itself.

So in this example the `shift` method operates *only* on an instance of `Point`.

So if I try:

```
point1 = Point(3, -5)
point1.shift(4, 4)
print(a.position)
```

I get:

```
[7, -1]
```

If instead I try to run:

```
Point.shift(4, 4)
```

I will receive a `TypeError` because there is no instance of `Point` for `shift` to operate on.

**Function arguments --** The line

```
def update_length(self, *args,measurements, measurements1, Text_Length_Left, Text_Length_Right):
```

Will give you errors. You should only use unpacking (`*args`) if you would like to handle a variable amount of arguments, or if the function takes many arguments that you would like to keep bundled together. If you use `*args` and then try to specify more positional arguments afterwords, you will receive a `TypeError` because Python is not expecting more positional arguments after `*args`. You can however have keyword arguments after `*args`.

Now after you fix your arguments in `update_length`, your calls to the function will still raise errors. Currently, your 3 calls to `update_length` are of the form:

```
Logic.self.update_length()
```

Due to my explanation on instance methods you first need to remove the `self` keyword. You only use this keyword in the class definition, you will receive errors if used anywhere else. Additionally, you will need to instantiate `Logic` somewhere that the class `GUI` has access to. Something like:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.logic = Logic(a, b, c, d)
        ...
        self.logic.update_length(e, f, g, h)
```

Noting that your current calls to `update_length` do not provide any of the positional arguments that you required. Your current definition of `update_length` requires 4 positional arguments (`measurements, measurements1, Text_Length_Left, Text_Length_Right`), but none are provided when the function is called.

I hope this is helpful, I think you should look at one or 2 more tutorials and then come back to your code.

Comment: Wow man thanks for the help! Have you copied the code an got it to work?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the code is supposed to do. Try to fix some of the problems I mentioned, then perhaps we can make it work.

Comment: Can we talk in a chat?

Comment: Sure, though i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: add me on skype regge12345

Answer (score 0):

The problem is easy: just remove `self`

`self.measurements.trace('w', Logic.update_length())`

When you calling a static function is `Class.Function()`. The `self` is not put. Reviewing your code, you must create the class `Logic` because `update_length()` is not static and then call the function:

```
logic_class = Logic()
self.measurements.trace('w', logic_class.update_length())
```

Comment: It won't run without `self.` or it will come up with the error `measurements.trace('w', Logic().self.update_length())`

Comment: Now I get the error `TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'measurements', 'measurements1', 'Text_Length_Left', and 'Text_Length_Right'`

Comment: because when you create a Logic class you must give the parameters that you define

Comment: I never have used tkinter package, for interface I use pyqt. But your problem is your python usage.

Comment: Could you try and fix the python usage?

Comment: It would be something like this: 
`logic_class = Logic([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 4)`. And them in your GUI class: `self.measurements.trace('w', logic_class.update_length())`

Comment: Hey man can I talk to you on skype about it? add me regge12345

Comment: I have not skype. long story. think in other way to contact me

Comment: Do you have teamspeak or discord which is online based skype

Comment: men, I write from Cuba. This internet is very slow and restricted. search me on [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/reinier.hernandezavila) or [trillian](https://www.trillian.im)

Comment: Or can you try edit my code and try it your way that would be so helpful if you could!